# MVC : Cant access js file via HttpGet/Post Method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am Doing simple get Operation by using MVC 3.0 + Jquery + HTTPGet/Post Method.My js was working fine few Hours Ago .Instantly it was getting erro for js not found ..the physical path is same as before ...

The Debuger Hits View on Runtime ..But cant hit Get Method

My _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/dashboard/eut.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

Controller

```
  public class EUTController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetSite()  {//getOperation }

        public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }

    }
```

MyView

```
@model Dashboard.Model.SoftwareReadiness.SwReadiness

<p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()))
</p>
```

My eut.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 getProducts();

});

function getProducts() {

    $.post("EUT/GetSite", null,
            function (jsonResult) {
                alert(jsonResult);
            })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert( errorThrown); });
```

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="repositoryMappingsConfiguration" type="Infrastructure.RepositoryFramework.Configuration.RepositorySettings, Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    <section name="entityMappingsConfiguration" type="Infrastructure.EntityFactoryFramework.Configuration.EntitySettings, Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>

        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <!--<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>-->

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <repositoryMappingsConfiguration>
    <repositoryMappings>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISiteRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Sites.SiteRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IProductRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Products.ProductRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISupplierRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Suppliers.SupplierRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IUserRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Users.UserRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IConfigRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Configs.ConfigRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IUserConfigRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.UserConfigs.UserConfigRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ICustomerRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Customers.CustomerRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IDRightRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.DRights.DRightRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IURightRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.URights.URightRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ITestLocationRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.TestLocations.TestLocationRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ICountryRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Countries.CountryRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IActivityRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Activitys.ActivityRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IAutoSmsRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.AutoSmss.AutoSmsRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IPriorityErrorRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.PriorityErrors.PriorityErrorRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IClaimRateRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.ClaimRates.ClaimRateRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IProductClaimRateRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.ProductClaimRates.ProductClaimRateRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISymptomClaimRateRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.SymptomClaimRates.SymptomClaimRateRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IMtbfTrendRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.MtbfTrends.MtbfTrendRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ILOCRRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.LOCRs.LOCRRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISurveyRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Surveys.SurveyRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISurveyQuestionRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.SurveyQuestions.SurveyQuestionRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISurveyQuestionOptionRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.SurveyQuestionOptions.SurveyQuestionOptionRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISurveyAnswerRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.SurveyAnswers.SurveyAnswerRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISurveyResponseRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.SurveyResponses.SurveyResponseRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ITestActivityRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.TestActivitys.TestActivityRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IScoreProfileRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.ScoreProfiles.ScoreProfileRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="ISwReadinessRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.SoftwareReadiness.SwReadinessRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IIndiaPriorityErrorRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.IndiaPriorityErrors.IndiaPriorityErrorRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IAolRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Aols.AolRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IFMIRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.FMIs.FMIRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IIndiaOCRTrendRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.IndiaOCRTrends.IndiaOCRTrendRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IConsumerInteractionRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.ConsumerInteractions.ConsumerInteractionRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IConsumerInteractionProductSpecificRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.ConsumerInteractionProductSpecifics.ConsumerInteractionProductSpecificRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IMainPageRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.MainPages.MainPageRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IMainPageConsumerInteractionProSpRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.MainConsumerInteractionProSps.MainPageConsumerInteractionProSpRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IMainPageConsumerInteractionRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.MainPageConsumerInteractions.MainPageConsumerInteractionRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IOCRepairRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.OCRepairs.OCRepairRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IOCRSymptomRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.OCRSymptoms.OCRSymptomRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IOCRCategoryDetailsRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.OCRCategoryDetail.OCRCategoryDetailsRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IOCRComponentSymptomRepositoty" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.OCRComponent.OCRComponentSymptomRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IEABRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.EABs.EABRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="URLRootRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.URLRoots.URLRootRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="URLDetailRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.URLDetails.URLDetailRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IQuestionnaireRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Questionnaires.QuestionnaireRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IQuestionnairePageRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.QuestionnairePages.QuestionnairePageRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IQuestionnaireContainerRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.QuestionnaireContainers.QuestionnaireContainerRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IQuestionnaireQuestionRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.QuestionnaireQuestions.QuestionnaireQuestionRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IQuestionnaireQuestionElementRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.QuestionnaireQuestionElements.QuestionnaireQuestionElementRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IQuestionnaireQuestionHistoryRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.QuestionnaireQuestionHistorys.QuestionnaireQuestionHistoryRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IActivitySWRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.ActivitySWs.ActivitySWRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IUFZillaErrorStatusRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Ufzerrorstat.UFZillaErrorStatusRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <repositoryMapping interfaceShortTypeName="IOCRDecibelRepository" repositoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.OCRDecibelDetail.OCRDecibelDetailRepository, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </repositoryMappings>
  </repositoryMappingsConfiguration>
  <entityMappingsConfiguration>
    <entityMappings>
      <entityMapping entityShortTypeName="Site" entityFactoryFullTypeName="Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories.Sites.SiteFactory, Dashboard.Infrastructure.Repositories, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
     ...SO ON
  </entityMappingsConfiguration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="360" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.upload" verb="*" type="JQueryFileUpload.FileUploadHandler"/>

      <add verb="POST"
             path="HighchartsExport.axd"
             type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

      <add verb="POST" path="HighchartsExport.axd" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

    </httpHandlers>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>-->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

I saw similar posts ..It was suggsted to change setting of IIS ..and add

```
<add path="*.upload" verb="*" type="JQueryFileUpload.FileUploadHandler"/>
```

I did this ..But it is not working..
Please Suggest

Comment: its a permissions issue, you gotta make sure iis is configured to access folder

Comment: Can you  please specify any good post for it ..I tried to search ..found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782574/no-access-to-files-in-iis7-mvc-app-server-2008-r2 ... it says set new AppPool for my website which has the Identity set to ApplicationPoolIdentity .. i DID that ..still it is not working

Comment: did you add your username/password as a local user on the app pool ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your permissions for IIS. By default in IIS 7, websites run as the local system's network account (NetworkService), not as IIS_User. Just add your local user to the app pool.

**Procedures**

Important   You must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer to perform the following procedure or procedures. As a security best practice, log on to your computer by using an account that is not in the Administrators group, and then use the runas command to run IIS Manager as an administrator. At a command prompt, 
type

`runas /user:Administrative_AccountName "mmc %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\iis.msc`".

To change the account under which an application pool runs using IIS Manager

1.In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, expand Application Pools, right-click the application pool, and then click Properties.

2.Click the Identity tab, and click either Predefined or Configurable. Predefined refers to standard service names, such as Network Service (the default), LocalSystem, or Local Service. Configurable refers to registered user names.

•   If you click Predefined, click a predefined account in the list box.

•   If you click Configurable, in the User name and Password boxes, type the user name and password of the account under which you want the worker process to operate. Then, add the account to the IIS_WPG group.

3.**Click OK.**

**Additional links**

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f05a7c2b-36b0-4b6e-ac7c-662700081f25.mspx?mfr=true

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/12a3d96c-65ea-4210-96ad-86a801f6a88c.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: My IIS version is iis 6  ..I searched a lot..I cant upgrade it to 7 or can use diffrent Operating Version..only use express ...How to add user in iis 6 or iis 7  express ,I could not able to found ..Can you suggest some specific steps ..thanks